# Json.Net проблемы сериализации

Tags: .net, json, serialize, json.net

Пытаюсь сериализовать класс, приложение падает или из-за переполнения стека, или падает на сериализации таких вещей, как потоки. Можно ли как-то промаркировать свойства для исключения из процесса сериализации?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

У вас несколько путей:

- `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptOut)]` на классе (по умолчанию)
  `[JsonIgnore]` на членах, которые вы не хотите сериализовать.
- `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.OptIn)]` на классе
  `[JsonProperty]` на членах, которые вы хотите сериализовать.
- `[JsonObject(MemberSerialization.Fields)]` на классе
  `[JsonIgnore]` на полях, которые вы не хотите сериализовать.

Answer (score 2):

Используйте [JsonIgnoreAttribute](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonIgnoreAttribute.htm)